# How to connect to O365 bypassing MFA in powershell

Tags: powershell, multi-factor-authentication

I am working with PowerShell. So we can connect MFA enabled O365 through connect-exopssession but we need to manully enter password and Code sent to mobile. But I want to schedule a solution which has to connect to O365 automtically without any manual intervention in MFA enabled O365. Is there any solution which can bypass MFA without disabling MFA in O365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is to setup an account that is dedicated for these types of tasks and remove MFA for it, or use Conditional Access to bypass MFA when connecting from your Public IP etc. Just make sure that you secure this account as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

To create non-interactive scripts, you need EXO V2 PowerShell module version 2.0.3 preview or later version. This unattended script authentication uses Azure AD applications, certificates, and Modern authentication.

Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell with existing service principal and client-secret:
To connect Exchange online with existing service principal and client-secret, you need to follow the steps below.

Step1: Get an OAuth access token using Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) PowerShell.

Step 2: Create `PSCredential` object

```
$AppCredential= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential(<UPN>,<Token>)
```

Step 3: Pass the `PSCredential` to the EXO V2 module.

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $AppCredential
```

For more information please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#setup-app-only-authentication

Answer (score 0):

Use App passwords. App passwords do not need MFA.
From docs:
An app password is a code that gives an app or device permission to access your Office 365 account. If your admin has turned on multi-factor authentication for your organization, and you're using apps that connect to your Office 365 account, you'll need to generate an app password, so the app can connect to Office 365.

Read more and how to in MS Docs [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/manage-app-passwords-for-two-step-verification-d6dc8c6d-4bf7-4851-ad95-6d07799387e9):